# How To Resolve Issue with Amplify Signup UI in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Using React Native I am using the following dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^7.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.2.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.8",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^6.0.1",
    "expo": "^37.0.7",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-android-dialog-picker": "^0.1.0",
    "react-proxy": "1.1.8"
  }
```

I am using the Amplify component for react native. I can click on the `Forget Password` and get the UI to appear. However when I click on `Sign Up` I get an error.

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCAndroidDialogPicker" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
in RNCAndroidDialogPicker(created by ForwardRef(PickerAndroid))
in ForwardRef(PickerAndroid) (created by Picker)
...
AmplifyUI.tsx:250)
in Wrapper (at SignUp.tsx:247)
...
```

How can I fix this issue and why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with react native CLI.

I solved it by installing the "@react-native-picker/picker" dependency.

I think your problem is derived that you have:
"@react-native-community/picker" and "@react-native-picker/picker".

you should only have one of those

Answer (score 0):

Above is correct, had the same issue with expo. this solved it.

first

```
yarn remove @react-native-community/picker
```

then

```
yarn add @react-native-picker/picker
```